# Could I use "whom" instead of "which" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

> More than 170 countries offer Chinese courses, 67 of ____ have incorporated Chinese into their national education systems.

the answer is "which"，I wonder whether It can be "whom".

Answer (score 4):

‘which’ is correct but ‘whom’ is not.

This is because ‘whom’ is usually only used to refer to people (which is not the case in your question).

Therefore, it would be better if you said “More than 170 countries offer Chinese courses, 67 of which (referring to the 170 countries) have incorporated Chinese into their national education systems.”